# Adding angular as maven module in maven project

Tags: java, angular, maven

I am working in multi maven project which is separated in the following modules:

- rest layer
- service layer
- repository layer

I want to add another module called view layer, ui of the application. The only problem is that ui is angular, and i need somehow to integrate angular app in maven module for this project.

I created a new maven module called view layer.  Added the following plugin it maven module pom of view layer like below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <nodeVersion>v8.11.3</nodeVersion>
        <npmVersion>6.3.0</npmVersion>
        <workingDirectory>src/main/web/</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm run build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>run build</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>prod</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
            </configuration>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And generated an angular app with angular cli inside src/main/web directory of view module.
Unfortunately the build is failing, it is not finding the package.json.

I will appreciate any help.

Regards,
Darth Bato.

Comment: Have you checked that `package.json` is indeed located at `src/main/web/package.json` (and not at `src/main/web/yourproject/package.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it this way to add angular as a maven module, in a multi maven project.

First thing I add a simple maven module by skipping the archetype selection. I modify the pom by adding the following configurations:

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>install</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>run</argument>
                                <argument>build</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Next, I delete all the content in the module I created only leaving the pom file. I delete the src folder, test folder, etc that are creating when we create a Maven module.

After that,  I create a new angular app by using ANGULAR CLI. I move all the content of the angular app(src, dist, nodes_modules, etc) to the maven module project.

In the end, to check if everything is ok, I run a maven build to parent maven project to see if everything compiles successfully.

Comment: This assumes that node and npm are installed (in the right version) on all machines running this build, which is quite fragile. The frontend-maven-plugin OP uses will automatically download and use node and npm in the version specified. Ditching the frontend-maven-plugin for the exec-maven-plugin therefore makes the build less portable across machines, and btw is wholly unnecessary for solving OP's problem.

Comment: Yes, it is true, for this solution to work, it required that the node js and npm are already installed.  I think this is better way because you specify the version of node js and npm needed in readme file and the developer are able to download the right version of node js. In my team I have used this approach and with the help of nvm we never had any problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think your

```
 <workingDirectory>src/main/web/</workingDirectory>
```

is not correcte since you've not added the module name

like this

```
<workingDirectory>frontend-module/src/main/web/</workingDirectory>
```

thats is why it cannot get your package.json